# Curly braces in HTML name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, getelementsbyname

I'm trying to retrieve DOM elements based on their name. Unfortunately their names have curly braces `{}` inside of them.

jQuery (1.6.4) is able to retrieve them without a problem. But at this point I am trying to replace these calls with `getElementsByName()`, but gEBN is not matching anything that has curly brackets in the query string. I have tried backslash escaping it once and twice to no avail.

Is there a way to do this without changing the convention of using the curly brackets?

[It also looks like](http://razzed.com/2009/01/30/valid-characters-in-attribute-names-in-htmlxml/) they are not in the set of characters allowed in the name attr.

**Update**: Seems to work in Chrome but not Safari for Windows. But what's really strange is that even Safari for Windows handles those fiddles fine.

Comment: This seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/sachinyadav/p7bNZ/

Comment: Not sure what the issue you have see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x7Xe5/ it works

Comment: Damn. Looks like this means more testing is needed if it is not fiddle-produceable

Comment: _"It also looks like they are not in the set of characters allowed in the name attr."_ **then don't use invalid names...** solved! :)

Comment: I agree with @gdoron.  There are rules for a reason ;)

Comment: @StevenLu: Have you seen this article? http://www.howtogeek.com/132602/safari-for-windows-is-probably-dead-how-to-migrate-to-another-browser/

Comment: @Mottie, thanks, I hadn't realized Apple was gonna kill off Windows support entirely.

Comment: @gdoron You must not hold me accountable for code written by my coworkers ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the jQuery documentation page on [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), you'll see this:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\`. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`.

Comment: Well, then I guess a demo of the problem is in order :P

Comment: The question is about the native JS solution which explicitly avoids taking the (already working) jQuery route. But yeah. I... can't actually reproduce it now, outside of an extremely specific case right now with a page that is inside 3 layers of frames.

Answer (score 1):

You should expect "strange" results when you do things that are explicitly outside what the standard allows.  If you choose to go off the reservation, you're kinda on your own.  Some browsers will work, some won't.  Ones that used to work will break without warning when a new version comes out.

So it depends what you're trying to do.  If you're just building something for yourself or a small team, this might be okay.  If you're building something for a general audience, better to stick to the standards and not use dis-allowed characters.